# R: applying function over matrix and keeping matrix dimensions

Tags: r

So I want to apply a function over a matrix in R. This works really intuitively for simple functions:

```
> (function(x)x*x)(matrix(1:10, nrow=2))
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    9   25   49   81
[2,]    4   16   36   64  100
```

...but clearly I don't understand all of its workings:

```
> m = (matrix(1:10, nrow=2))
> (function(x) if (x %% 3 == 0) { return(NA) } else { return(x+1) })(m)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    4    6    8   10
[2,]    3    5    7    9   11
Warning message:
In if (x == 3) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I read up on this and found out about Vectorize and sapply, which both seemed great and just like what I wanted, except that both of them convert my matrix into a list:

```
> y = (function(x) if (x %% 3 == 0) { return(NA) } else { return(x+1) })
> sapply(m, y)
 [1]  2  3 NA  5  6 NA  8  9 NA 11
> Vectorize(y)(m)
 [1]  2  3 NA  5  6 NA  8  9 NA 11
```

...whereas I'd like to keep it in a matrix with its current dimensions. How might I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Also check out this useful post on the different versions of apply: http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

@Joshua Ulrich (and Dason) has a great answer. And doing it directly without the function `y` is the best solution. But if you really *need* to call a function, you can make it faster using `vapply`. It produces a vector *without* dimensions (as `sapply`, but faster), but then you can add them back using `structure`:

```
# Your function (optimized)
y = function(x) if (x %% 3) x+1 else NA

m <- matrix(1:1e6,1e3)
system.time( r1 <- apply(m,1:2,y) ) # 4.89 secs
system.time( r2 <- structure(sapply(m, y), dim=dim(m)) ) # 2.89 secs
system.time( r3 <- structure(vapply(m, y, numeric(1)), dim=dim(m)) ) # 1.66 secs
identical(r1, r2) # TRUE
identical(r1, r3) # TRUE
```

...As you can see, the `vapply` approach is about 3x faster than `apply`... And the reason `vapply` is faster than `sapply` is that `sapply` must analyse the result to figure out that it can be simplified to a numeric vector. With `vapply`, you specified the result type (`numeric(1)`), so it doesn't have to guess...

**UPDATE** I figured out another (shorter) way of preserving the matrix structure:

```
m <- matrix(1:10, nrow=2)
m[] <- vapply(m, y, numeric(1))
```

You simply assign the new values to the object using `m[] <-`. Then all other attributes are preserved (like `dim`, `dimnames`, `class` etc).

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I agree in retrospect that with the toy example I gave skipping the actual function was the right call, but I really wanted to know how this should be handled when it is actually a function. (I tried to contrive one to that effect that was simpler than the one I was really dealing with, but evidently missed the mark.) Anyway having the timing information is super helpful because I am trying to optimize this as well -- thanks!

Answer (score 16):

One way is to use `apply` on both rows and columns:

```
apply(m,1:2,y)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2   NA    6    8   NA
[2,]    3    5   NA    9   11
```

You can also do it with subscripting because `==` is already vectorized:

```
m[m %% 3 == 0] <- NA
m <- m+1
m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2   NA    6    8   NA
[2,]    3    5   NA    9   11
```

Answer (score 8):

For this specific example you can just do something like this

```
> # Create some fake data
> mat <- matrix(1:16, 4, 4)
> # Set all elements divisible by 3 to NA
> mat[mat %% 3 == 0] <- NA
> # Add 1 to all non NA elements
> mat <- mat + 1
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    6   NA   14
[2,]    3   NA   11   15
[3,]   NA    8   12   NA
[4,]    5    9   NA   17
```

Comment: A coworker pointed this approach out to me. It does fulfill my need and I appreciate it, but it really seems like there should be some way to apply a pre-existing function over a matrix.

Answer (score 7):

There's a slight refinement of Dason and Josh's solution using `ifelse`.

```
mat <- matrix(1:16, 4, 4)
ifelse(mat %% 3 == 0, NA, mat + 1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    6   NA   14
[2,]    3   NA   11   15
[3,]   NA    8   12   NA
[4,]    5    9   NA   17
```

Comment: Nice one. this would be the fastest. a quick check using `rbenchmark` shows that it is around 8x faster than the `vapply` solution. Vectorization always triumpsh!!