# R: Change cell value in matrix keeping matrix format

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I have a matrix I want to change. If a cell value is 3, I want to change it to 5 (obviously a simplification of my problem)

```
testM <- matrix(1:10, ncol = 2)
```

First I thought that a simple

```
testM[which(x == 3)] = 5
```

could make it, but the testM matrix is not modified.

Then what I tried is:

```
f <- function(x) if (x == 3) 5
```

If I write vapply expressions all they give an error:

```
newM <- vapply (testM, f, numeric(1))
newM <- vapply (testM, f, matrix())
newM <- vapply (testM, f, matrix(NA,5,2))

Error in vapply(testM, f, matrix(NA, 5, 2)) : values must be length 10,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 0
```

The solution proposed in [R: applying function over matrix and keeping matrix dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579257/r-applying-function-over-matrix-and-keeping-matrix-dimensions#8579498)
does not work for me:

```
Error in vapply(testM, f, numeric(1)) : values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 0
```

Comment: maybe `testM[testM == 3] <- 5` with matrix indexing? See `?"["` and the third paragraph of the Matrices and arrays section for a detailed description. Or `testM[which(testM == 3, arr.ind=TRUE)] <- 5` for the same result if you're into the unnecessary use of `which`.

Comment: Also, `if` is not vectorized, as in it will only work a logical vector of length 1, so `if (x == 3)` will only make sense if `length(x)` is 1. For that, you could use `ifelse(x == 3, 5, x)` instead.

Comment: My first suggestion is equivalent to josh ulrich's suggestion of `m[m %% 3 == 0] <- NA` in the post you linked to.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the problem:

```
testM[testM == 3] = 5
```

or

```
testM[which(testM == 2)] = 5
```

I dont get why you putted x inside which